# Simple command to connect to FTPS server on Linux command line

Tags: command-line, ftp, ftps

I have an FTP and FTPS server where I can connect to easily with FileZilla. I'm looking for a linux CLI method. I thought `lftp` does it, but it seems weird. Is there another way?

Here is the method I found on Google to connect to my FTPS with `lftp`. But I hope there is an easier way:

```
lftp -c 'open -e "set ftps:initial-prot ""; \
   set ftp:ssl-force true; \
   set ftp:ssl-protect-data true; \
   put test.txt; " \
   -u "USERNAME","PASSWORD" \
   ftps://HOSTNAME:990 '
```

The code I got above looks like it will fail – haven't tried it yet as I don't like it, I know that the `\` need to be at the end of the line.

I'm looking for a much simpler one liner. Here is how I connect from any FileZilla client and it works:

```
ftps://username:password@ftp.server.com/
```

Also, this works:

```
ftps://username:password@ftp.server.com/
```

Comment: You should probably separate this into two different questions, since they really are.

Comment: Please read: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://superuser.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 20):

I don't know whether this wasn't available on the 2013 version of lftp, but now you can simply do:

```
lftp -u YOUR_USER HOST_ADDRESS
```

For example, to connect to host `192.168.1.50` with user `test`, you only type the following:

```
lftp -u test 192.168.1.50
```

Answer (score 12):

If by weird you mean a long command line with both types of quotes, just avoid it. 
Use a script and save a bookmark. There are probably no better ftp clients than lftp.

1. save your lftp script in a file
2. run lftp without any arguments
3. source the script
4. save a bookmark.
5. delete rhe script (to get rid of the clear-text password)

Use the bookmark in the future. You'll have to figure out if ssl options are saved 
for the bookmark or if you have to persist those settings via a global lftp configuration file.

---

Sample script.

```
$ cat lftp.ssl.commands
user moo foopass
set ftps:initial-prot "";
set ftp:ssl-force true;
set ftp:ssl-protect-data true;
open ftps://HOSTNAME:990
```

---

Sample output.

```
$ lftp
lftp :~> source  lftp.ssl.commands
lftp HOSTNAME:~> dir
`ls' at 0 [Connecting...]
```

Answer (score 8):

Or you can do this in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
lftp <<SCRIPT
set ftps:initial-prot ""
set ftp:ssl-force true
set ftp:ssl-protect-data true
open ftps://<hostname>:990
user <user> <password>
lcd /tmp
cd <ftp_folder_hierarchy>
put foo.txt
exit
SCRIPT
```

This shouldn't create any permanent lftp changes in /etc/lftp.conf, or ~/.lftprc, or ~/.lftp/rc

Answer (score 7):

it will fail on some servers, because ssl settings should be passed before the open command not within it. example of working one:

```
lftp -c 'set ftp:ssl-allow true ; set ssl:verify-certificate no; open -u USERNAME,PASSWORD -e "cd /; mput LOCAL/PATH/TO/FILE/FILENAME.EXT; quit" HOST'
```

Answer (score 6):

I tried to connect to Proftpd server with above config but it does not work.

But, when I try to connect with the following config, it works:

1. Create a config file with `vi`:

   ```
   vi .lftprc
   ```
2. Put the following content in `.lftprc` file:

   ```
   set ftp:ssl-auth TLS
   set ftp:ssl-force true
   set ftp:ssl-protect-list yes
   set ftp:ssl-protect-data yes
   set ftp:ssl-protect-fxp yes
   set ssl:verify-certificate no
   ```
3. Connect to the server with:

   ```
   lftp username@hostname
   ```

And that's it!

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me in Ubuntu connecting to an AzureWebApp via FTPS.

Answer (score 5):

**Simple**

Here you have: `ftp-ssl`

Per default tries to connect via SSL or TLS. It needs **no particular options** or settings. And if secure connection is not available performs a standard FTP connection.

```
ftp-ssl <Server IP address or Server Name>
```

For example, `ftp-ssl 192.168.35.100` or `ftp-ssl lovedByJesus`

An excerpt [from the documentation](https://packages.debian.org/sid/ftp-ssl):

> ftp-ssl replaces normal ftp using SSL or TLS authentication and
> encryption. It interoperates with normal ftpd. It checks if the other
> side is also talking SSL or TLS, if not it falls back to normal ftp
> protocol.